# Set field by order by rank, but in another field's groups

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm new here, and very stumped by a mysql problem.

My table has the fileds:
username VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, score INT, rank INT

I'm trying to set the rank field based on users scores, but by state individually.

I've found I can set ranks for them all if I ignore state:

> SET @pos := 0; UPDATE profiles SET rank = ( SELECT @pos := @pos +
>   1 ) ORDER BY cash DESC

and I can set it for a single state like this:

> "SET @pos := 0; UPDATE profiles SET rank = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 )
>   WHERE homeState = 'Arizona' ORDER BY cash DESC"

Is it possible to group them by state, and set their ranks by state in a single query, rather than 50 individual ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a `select` as:

```
select p.*,
       (@rn := if(@s = state, @rn + 1,
                  if(@s := state, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
from profiles p cross join
     (select @s := '', @rn := 0) params
order by state, score desc;
```

To put this in an update, you can use `join`:

```
update profiles p join
       (select p.*,
               (@rn := if(@s = state, @rn + 1,
                          if(@s := state, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as rn
        from profiles p cross join
             (select @s := '', @rn := 0) params
        order by state, score desc
       ) pp
       on p.username = pp.username
    set p.rank = pp.rn;
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the help! However, this is still giving me a tough time. The update query provided appears to ignore score when assigning rank. Given the table entries: >bilbo, arizona, 5, 0

Comment: Given the table entries: bilbo, arizona, 5, 0 | fam, alaska, 1, 0 | dug, alaska, 0, 0 | frodo, arizona, 2, 0 | zidon, arizona, 3, 0. I expect ranks to be 1,1,2,3,2 but i get 1,1,2,1,2.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that for "rank = rn", rank was ambiguous. I had to do p.rank = rn, so maybe that could be a problem.

Comment: Hey, for anybody wondering, it seems to work okay now after removing "cross join
     (select @s := '', @rn := 0) params" for some reason.  Although I'm not sure the purpose of that line, so remove it at your own risk :D.

Comment: @ZacharyNelson . . . That code initializes the variables.  It is hard to see how it could break anything.